# How to get google user photo? Android Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-signin

How can I retrieve a photo of the user? I have successfully get user name and email address, but i don't know how to get user's profile picture and load it into the Image View. How to do that?

I have tried.

```
 auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
  val x = auth!!.currentUser!!.photoUrl.toString()
  imageView!!.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(x))
```

But it doesn't work

[image]

Comment: try with Glide or Picasso liblary

Comment: Is `auth!!.currentUser!!.photoUrl.toString()` a url that you can open in your browser? Also, be careful using `!!` everywhere, Kotlin is intended to be null safe; now it will still crash when it encounters a null.

Comment: That link can be opened, i have put  some random link image. However, the image view can't load the image from the others link too.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me using Glide. I used java code though.

**First**, implement Glide module in you gradle app:

```
// Glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

**Second**, create a class that extends AppGlideModule.
This class registers a FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference.
Don't forget annotations or it won't work.

```
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
        registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
                new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }

}
```

**Third**, load the image in your image view

```
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference yourPicRererence = storage.getReference().child("Path to your picture");
    
                GlideApp.with(getContext()) /* your context */
                        .load(yourPicRererence) /* your picture*/
                        .centerCrop() /* this is optional */
                        .into(imageView); /* your image view*/
```

(Source: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage)